# ubuntu wireless connected but wont load websites - 14.04 LTS x64

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm a beginner when it comes to linux and i've already read through and tried out everything i have found in countless other threads. So keep in mind that i might have made more problems for myself. But i am willing to reinstall ubuntu and then start fixing it from scratch, if needed.

The problem is that i can connect to my wireless connection through wlan0. but then i can not use the internet in any way. If i use a browser it will load it halfway through the first time, but won't do it again afterwards.

google can sometimes be loaded on the first try, so the wifi seem to work until the second i use it.

Also, it's a fresh install.

I get no errors about disconnecting from wifi and the signal strength is excellent.

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:8f:b1:fc  
  inet addr:192.168.0.110  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::6e62:6dff:fe8f:b1fc/64 Scope:Link
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:11530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:8627 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:7151561 (7.1 MB)  TX bytes:1262467 (1.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:3105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:3105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
  RX bytes:309918 (309.9 KB)  TX bytes:309918 (309.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:87:12:01  
  inet addr:192.168.0.106  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe87:1201/64 Scope:Link
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:416 errors:0 dropped:68 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:636 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:342914 (342.9 KB)  TX bytes:80997 (80.9 KB)
```

**iwconfig**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MultiStation"  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
  Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:0C:F6:AD:E2:00   
  Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
  Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
  Power Management:off
  Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
  Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
  Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**netstat -rn**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

**route -n**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search sitecomwl341
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search sitecomwl341
```

I also tried:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

And edited in the following line even though i seem to use a different driver?:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

**nm-tool**

```
- Device: wlan0  [MultiStation] ------------------------------------------------
Type:              802.11 WiFi
Driver:            r8712u
State:             connected
Default:           no
HW Address:        00:E0:4C:87:12:01

Capabilities:
  Speed:           150 Mb/s

Wireless Properties
  WEP Encryption:  yes
  WPA Encryption:  yes
  WPA2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
  *MultiStation:   Infra, 00:0C:F6:AD:E2:00, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA2

IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         192.168.0.106
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         192.168.0.1

DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@2:1.4
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 00:e0:4c:87:12:01
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8712u ip=192.168.0.106 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Secondary PCI Express Root Port (rev 18)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks XT [Radeon HD 6670/7670]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series]
02:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0a5c:2148 Broadcom Corp. BCM92046DG-CL1ROM Bluetooth 2.1 Adapter
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8192 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:6360 Alcor Micro Corp. Multimedia Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Edit because of first answer:

When I try to enable wireless again, I get this error:

```
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$ sudo modprobe -r r8712u
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$ echo "0bda 8192" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
0bda 8192
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
wico@wico-MS-7708:~$
```

also, after disconnecting from my wireless it never seems to search for new wireless again, so i'll have to reboot if i want to connect to the same or another wireless again.

Comment: I do not see any wireless adapters there. Please add `lsusb` too.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists even with the new driver, reboot and with my wired connection disabled.

Comment: Check update pls

Comment: Right after i use 'sudo modprobe -r r8712u' the terminal won't let me write down new input, but trying to close the terminal will say that there's still a process running. Do i just keep waiting or is something wrong?

Comment: Disable your wireless network first. Then reboot and try again.

Comment: I've updated my question with the input from your answer.

Comment: I met this adapter before, but I do not remember how to fix it. Deleting my answer.

Comment: Maybe buy a usb external dongle?

Comment: I've got a wireless network card laying around, i'll try that one out. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question still hasn't been answered I figured I might answer it myself with what I believe is the best solution. I've run unto this problem before in the past few years so it's safe to assume that it's not something that's going to be fixed soon. Even though I was able to get my network card working the previous times, it always cost me a day or two.

And whenever you reinstall or move to another Linux distribution, you have to do it all over again. It seems like none of the distributions like certain network cards.

Best bet is to get a USB WiFi Dongle (they're cheap) as they all seem to instantly get recognized and installed by most Linux distributions and then you'll be able to browse the internet again.